# Strange Status 420 in HttpStatusException - jsoup

Tags: multithreading, jsoup, http-status-codes

I've got strange problem associated with getting HTML Document from URL address.

This is code that concerns it.

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(address);
conn.timeout(10 * 1000);
Connection.Response resp = conn.execute();
if (resp.statusCode() == 200)
     return conn.get();
```

I'm creating multithreaded app in which many threads try to establish connect to the appropriate address and get HTML Document. Unfortunately, for most threads conn.execute() throws HttpStatusException with strange http status code that equals 420. I can't find solution for this problem.

EDIT:

After testing that based on changing the number of threads, it turns out that this HttpStatusException with http status code 420 disappear when the number of threads estimates 5-10. Hovewer, this number concerns only kind of threads that are responsible for getting appropriate data from Urls like e.g. https://www.laczynaspilka.pl/rozgrywki/nizsze-ligi-juniorzy,16450.html. As for getting data from Urls like https://www.laczynaspilka.pl/druzyny/ekstraklasa,1.html, i can create about 60-70 threads of this type and HttpStatusException with status 420 isn't thrown. Is it possible that urls from the same website have 'different limits of request number' ?

Comment: What service or website are you connecting to? 420 isn't an official HTTP status code, but Twitter historically used it to indicate that you were being throttled for making too many requests too quickly. Twitter has since replaced this with 429, but other APIs may have copied their original design.

Comment: It is polish website laczynaspilka.pl . I know that this http status code was connected with Twitter but i don't think that I make too many request because I have various types of threads that use it and only one type of threads have this problem. To be more precisely, this threads differ source of URL addresses. In one case I take URL from other website (that is parsed). Otherwise I have to take from file.